# PHP how to replace second character of a string if it's a space

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I'm working with some OCR text and occasionally the first word of a line will be split. It should be

*For billing questions contact...*

but it's returning

*F or billing questions contact...*

I am using `preg_replace` with an array of patterns and replacements and looking for one to add to fix this.

I tried matching `/^. /` which works but I can't figure out the replacement pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
 '/^\S\K\s+/m'
```

and replace with an empty string. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o9MDdr/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (as `m` alows a `^` anchor to also match start of lines, not just start of a string)
- `\S` - a non-whitespace
- `\K` - match reset operator (it discards, zeros out, the current match value)
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars (what is actually put into the match value and is eventually replaced with an empty string).

Comment: Thanks! After I posted I was playing on RegExr and figured out this also works pattern: '/(^.)\s/'  replacement: '$1'